# Are quasicrystals common on the Moon and Mars?

Tags: mars, the-moon, geology

According to this 594, 7861 Nature article called [First nuclear detonation created ‘impossible’ quasicrystals](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-021-01332-0), the quasicrystals are readily created when where is an explosion or a meteorite impact because they generate a lot of energy. Therefore they should be wherever there are a lot of impact craters.

Have the quasicrystals ever been discovered on the Moon or Mars or are they expected to be found. Can existing rovers identify them if they come across a quasicrystal?

Comment: Don't know if they've been found on the moon or Mars, but the first known natural quasicrystalline mineral was found in material from an asteroid impact here on Earth: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosahedrite

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff but it's probably not *that impact* that produced the quasicrystalline material, cf. [It is thought that the icosahedrite, like the khatyrkite, was formed in space in a collision involving the parent body of the meteorite.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khatyrkite#Relation_to_quasicrystals) and [and then rapidly cooled after being heated during an impact-induced shock that occurred in outer space 4.5 Gya.](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep09111)

Answer (score 8):

On Mars, Curiosity has a [diffractometer](https://mars.nasa.gov/resources/4829/x-ray-diffraction-big-and-small/) so in principle it should be able to measure the Bragg diffraction that is used to detect quasicrystals.  However, such analysis may not have been done yet.

Comment: I've just asked [How does Curiosity's X-ray diffractometer work? Does it measure only one angle at a time or does it have an area detector?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/52504/12102)