# Why are there four RTGs in a row sitting in this room? What are they waiting for? Were they built together and stored for separate launches?

Tags: nasa, cassini, rtg, manufacturing, jpl

The extremely cool NASA JPL video *Triumph at Saturn (Part I)* is really worth a watch and/or listen.

At about `17:40` it discusses Cassini's [RTG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radioisotope_thermoelectric_generator) and at `18:36` there is a shot of **four RTGs in a row** being checked for radiation levels.

RTGs have been in short supply, and because they start degrading as soon as they are assembled (or as soon as the radioisotope has been refined) they're not something one might just have a stock of laying around, or so it seems to me.

- [Which wears out faster on RTGs; the R's or the TG's? (the radioisotopes or the thermocouples)](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/44381/12102)

**Question:** Why are there four RTGs in a row sitting in this room? What are they waiting for? Were they built together and stored for separate launches?

[image: screenshot from the extremely cool NASA JPL video "Triumph at Saturn (Part I)"]

cued at `17:40`

Comment: I like the monoliths behind the RTGs too. Cue "Also sprach Zarathustra"

Comment: @OrganicMarble I saw the movie when it first came out in theaters (which somewhat dates me) and when I had learned to read better I read the book. I discovered math not in school, but in the dimensions of the monolith: the squares of the first three prime numbers. They pulled it off in Seattle [back in 2001](https://www.latimes.com/archives/la-xpm-2001-jan-04-mn-8191-story.html) (also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seattle_Monolith)) and again more recently. These are better looking, but a bit on the thin side for Clarke's tastes.

Comment: Yeah, I bugged my parents to take me to see it when it first came out. My dad slept blissfully through most of it. The soundtrack is the first vinyl LP I bought too. https://i.imgur.com/3syd5pL.png

Comment: I wouldn't stand that close if they were loaded.

Comment: @JamesErvin a radiation safety-trained person knows what to expect, and (as shown) carries instrumentation to check radiation levels, as well as a personal dosimeter. 238Pu is primarily an alpha particle emitter and those have a very short range (microns). In that sense it's like the 241Am alpha sources in smoke detectors, but a lot more powerful. There is a small neutron background, so you would not want to stand that close for a long time. My guess is that this is a unoccupied storage area to minimize large doses of thermal neutrons, and folks only visit for short periods of time.

Comment: @JamesErvin see for example [Does curiosity's RTG generate neutrons as this NASA CheMin X-ray detection system webpage suggests? If so, how?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/52515/12102) Since I'm just guessing about this, you might consider asking how these are stored and how much time people spend in the room with them as a new question!

Comment: @uhoh it was a joke that I wanted to make but didn't have quite the right wording, regardless, I'm going to take a look into what you sent me. It looks very interesting!

Comment: @JamesErvin yep got it! Historically there has been some public pushback about launching spacecraft with RTGs due to safety concern, both in public discourse and in protests, e.g. "What if it blows up on the launch pad, will we all die?" In the video they show a clip of a press event before launch where some members of the panel even attest that they have brought family members to the launch as a way of showing confidence that the RTG does not itself pose a safety risk. So I'm just covering the bases here for future readers. https://youtu.be/SY-hQJ5pMd4?t=1114

Answer (score 33):

There were seven General Purpose Heat Source - Radioisotope Thermal Generators (GPHS-RTGs) assembled (there were parts for an eighth).

The seven would eventually fly in space on four different spacecraft.

Perhaps we are looking at the 3 Cassini flight units and the New Horizons one.

> The flight units used by mission, with power levels at launch, were:
>
> - Galileo: Flight Units 1 (289 W<sub>e</sub>) and 4 (288 W<sub>e</sub>)
> - Ulysses: Flight Unit 3 (289 W<sub>e</sub>)
> - Cassini: Flight Units 2 (296 W<sub>e</sub>), 6 (294 W<sub>e</sub>) and 7 (298 W<sub>e</sub>)
> - New Horizons: Flight Unit 8 (245.7 W<sub>e</sub> at bus instead of connector pins)

The listed power levels are *electrical* power levels in watts (W<sub>e</sub>),

Sources

- [The Origins and History of the GPHS-RTG](https://beyondnerva.com/radioisotope-power-sources/gphs-rtg/) (nice article)
- [GPHS-RTGs in support of the Cassini RTG Program. Final technical report](https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/296824) (technical paper)

Comment: Wow, why did Cassini need three times the power of some of those other probes?

Comment: @NickS that would be another question ... feel free to ask it :)

Comment: What happened to Flight Unit 5?

Comment: @nick012000 From the first link: "[...] the Cassini and Ulysses backup RTG (Flight Unit 5, never flown) [...]", "[...] Flight Unit 5 was completely fueled and ready to be exchanged for a faulty unit, but was never needed."